# Add volume percentage to the menu bar?

Tags: macos, catalina, menu-bar, sound-volume

Does anyone know a solution to easily add the current output volume percentage to the menu bar?

Comment: I'm not aware of any way to do this, but methinks it's a useful idea. You could take this on as a personal project - [develop a Menu Bar app.](https://www.raywenderlich.com/450-menus-and-popovers-in-menu-bar-apps-for-macos)

Comment: Thanks. Don't have the skills and time myself to do so but hopefully someone else wants to jump in! :-)

Comment: Agreed! No patience for such *arcanery*.